# SFMC - Custom reply to address

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio, reply-mail-management

We are sending emails from:
newsletter@ourdomain.com

We want to set the reply-to addres to:
customerservice@ourdomain.com

We do NOT want to use RMM, and we do NOT want to have the reply forwarded via SFMC.

So when a contact clicks on 'reply' in the email client, the Reply To field in the client should be filled with customerservice@ourdomain.com.

How do we set this up?

- When we turn RMM off, I expect the reply address to be the one we entered in the: 'Email Reply Address' field under company --> Account --> General settings. But instead, the from address is simply used as reply address.
- All other options Using RMM, or the settings in the Sender Profile will have the reply address set as something like: 'reply-fedd015727664d0d7d-d-424497d46-522d966-2@ourdomain.nl'. Which will have the reply redirected via SFMC, which we don't want.

Comment: Have you been able to somehow solve this issue? we are experiencing the same issue.
Also, when you disable RMM (in case you don't want to see reply-fedd015727664d0d7d-d-424497d46-522d966-2@) reply functionality does not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

In the sender profile, choose to use a custom reply email address by ticking **Use custom settings below** and then **Use specified information**, where you can type in the reply-to name and email address:

[image]

Comment: Hi,  I did that. Entered customerservice@ourdomain.com in that field. 
In journey builder, when clicking on 'Message Configuration', it lists 'Reply Email = customerservice@ourdomain.com. (looking good).  But when clicking on 'Reply' in the inbox, the reply address is still the from address (newsletter@ourdomain.com)

Comment: Dod you create a new version of the journey or did you just modify the settings and saved the old version?

Comment: Above comment was with RMM disabled. When I set the above setting while having RMM enabled, the reply address is something like: reply-fec6s7sd746307s79-1d5s7_HTML-123456-12345-1@ourdomain.com instead of just customerservice@ourdomain.com

Comment: We are replying at the same time :).  Yes new version, and even a whole new email and new journey.
In addition, I understand wat the transformed email address does. It will send the reply first to SFMC, after which SFMC will forward the mail to the target inbox. But we don't want that. The customer should be able to send the reply directly to ustomerservice@ourdomain.com.